# Would a Shopping.StackExchange do any good?

Tags: discussion

Everyone—including me—agrees that [shopping / poll questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935756/what-is-the-most-user-friendly-asp-net-mvc-grid-view-control#comment12498711_935756) are not acceptable for StackOverflow.  The reasons why have been well articulated many times.

But most of these questions *do* have *some* good information in them; and they attract a lot of people.  Has anyone ever considered a shopping.StackExchange or a polls.StackExchange for this kind of stuff?

On the one hand I could see how this might benefit SE in that it would attract more viewers, and potentially more revenue.  But on the other hand I can see why purposefully  creating a ghetto like this might hurt the image of SE.

Is there anything I'm missing / not considering?

Comment: It's [just another trash can.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related)

Comment: Could we call it `/dev/null`?

Comment: My rep is a multiple of ten!!  *No more downvotes!!!*

Comment: I'll be impressed when it's a power of 2.  Or a prime.

Comment: @Robert - obligatory [xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/1000/)

Comment: Polls Stack Exchange? Why stop there? Why not Forum Stack Exchange? Or go Full Monty, and get us a nice Crap Stack Exchange... It'd be the most successful migration target on the network. ;P BTW, no one can guess if a site will be successful, why not try your luck at Area 51?

Comment: @Yannis - take it easy :)  The premise of the question is that polls have *some* valuable information in them.  The low information density makes them harmful to SO.  Just wondering whether there might be a place for them.  That's all.  Forums typically have no value.

Comment: @AdamRackis _Everything_ can have _some_ valuable information in it, that's not the point of Stack Exchange, the point is that _most_ of the content should be of high quality.

Comment: I think people downvoted this question because they didn't like the idea, not because the question is poorly formed or illegitimate. Shame.

Comment: @David - actually, voting on Meta is different.  Voting here is *supposed* to be based on whether you agree with the idea.

Comment: I'm surprised. I guess I should go read the FAQ. (Reads some of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) I can't find anything about why a question should be voted up or down. I'll keep your point in mind though since this is one of the first meta questions I've looked at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Has anyone ever considered a shopping.StackExchange or a polls.StackExchange for this kind of stuff?

Yes someone did propose it on Area 51, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38683/shopping

It was proposed about a month ago and closed with the following comment.

> This isn't really what we do. See https://stackexchange.com/about & https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ – Robert Cartaino ♦

Stack Exchange is not going to be the only tool to rule the information highway, Reddit and Quora are there to complement.

Comment: The curt comment with which you closed your answer misrepresented my question.  Thank you for the useful information which preceded it, though.

Comment: I agree. The answer is fine, but the last sentence is unnecessary. How is a question that ends in "Is there anything I'm missing / not considering?"  trying to shove something somewhere?